# Squared Residuals vs. Variance of Residuals (ARCH)

Tags: regression, econometrics, garch

I understand the intuition behind finding autocorrelation between the squared residuals to test for time conditional heteroskedasticity, but does $\epsilon^2$ really show $Var(\epsilon)$? One realization of the error term wouldn't necessarily translate to its estimated variance, would it? Am I misinterpreting the meaning of $Var(\epsilon)$ and/or how it is calculated?

Wouldn't it prove more accurate to model ARCH and quantify $\rho$ as follows?

$$Var(\epsilon(t)) = \rho*Var(\epsilon(t-1))$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $Var_{t}(\epsilon_{t+1})=E_{t}(\epsilon_{t+1}^{2})$ provided that $E_{t}(\epsilon_{t+1})=0$, so the conditional variance is not the simplest square of the innovation but the conditional expectation of the square (provided that obviously the conditional expected value of the residuals is 0).